# How to show asp.net chart grouped by 2 parameters

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, charts

I want to present some condensed data to the user using the `Chart` component.

SQL (C# / Oracle):

```
SELECT c.date, c.approved, count(distinct c.f1) amt_c, count(b.f1) amt_b, sum(b.value) sum_values
FROM contracts c
JOIN bens b ON c.ben_id = b.id
WHERE :YearMonth = to_char(c.date,'YYYYMM') AND NOT c.approved = 'REJECTED'
GROUP BY c.date, c.approved
ORDER BY c.date
```

I have this SQL in a method that passes a DataSet to the ObjectDataSource in the .aspx page  (The `approved` field can have 3 values: REJECTED, APPROVED and PENDING).

Chart in .aspx page:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="RelatorioDataSource" 
    Width="700px" Compression="10" Palette="Chocolate">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Contracts" XValueMember="date" 
            YValueMembers="amt_c" IsXValueIndexed="False" 
            XValueType="DateTime" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" BorderDashStyle="DashDot" 
            CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Emboss, EmptyPointValue=Zero, DrawSideBySide=True" 
            YValuesPerPoint="4">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series BorderDashStyle="DashDot" ChartArea="ChartArea1" 
            CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Emboss, EmptyPointValue=Zero, DrawSideBySide=True" 
            IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Name="Bens" 
            XValueMember="date" XValueType="DateTime" 
            YValueMembers="amt_b" YValuesPerPoint="4">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I want to show the numbers of approved/pending contracts/bens for each day (4 bars), but the chart shows only two columns.
[image: Column chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating an object `relatorio` to hold the returned data (instead of the DataSet), filtering the results using LINQ to Objects, and adding the series programmatically in codeBehind.

```
var approved = relatorio
    .Where(r => r.APPROVED == "APPROVED")
    .ToList()
    ;
var pending = relatorio
    .Where(r => r.APPROVED == "PENDING")
    .ToList()
    ;
```

Creating Legends

```
Legend legenda = new Legend("Legenda");
legenda.Docking = Docking.Bottom;
legenda.LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Row;
legenda.Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
```

Creating series in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Series temp = new Series {
        XAxisType = AxisType.Primary,
        XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime,
        YAxisType = AxisType.Primary,
        //mostra só a quantidade de contratos
        IsValueShownAsLabel = i % 2 == 0 ? true : false,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
        CustomProperties = "EmptyPointValue=Zero",
        Legend = "Legenda"
    };
    grafico.Series.Add(temp);
}
approvedValues.Points.DataBindXY(approved, "DATE", approved, "SUM_VALUES");
```

DataBinding series

```
// approved CONTRACTS
grafico.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(approved, "DATE", approved, "AMT_C");
grafico.Series[0].LegendText = "Contratos approved";
// approved BENS
grafico.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(approved, "DATE", approved, "AMT_B");
grafico.Series[1].LegendText = "Ben approved";
grafico.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
// pending CONTRACTS
grafico.Series[2].Points.DataBindXY(pending, "DATE", pending, "AMT_C");
grafico.Series[2].LegendText = "Contratos pending";
// pending BENS
grafico.Series[3].Points.DataBindXY(pending, "DATE", pending, "AMT_B");
grafico.Series[3].LegendText = "Ben pending";
grafico.Series[3].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a group for each series..

example:
`chart1.series[0]["StackedGroupName"] = "group1";`